# Add new column based on mean slice of another column

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a DataFrame

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], columns=['col_1'])
```

I would like to add a new column where the value of each row in the new column is the mean of the values in `col_1` starting at that row. In this case the new column (let's call it `'col_2'` would be `[30, 35, 40, 45, 50]`.

The following is not good code but it at least describes generating the values.

```
for i in range(len(my_df)):
    my_df.loc[i]['col_2'] = my_df[i:]['col_1'].mean()
```

How can I do this in a clean, idiomatic way that doesn't raise a `SettingWithCopyWarning`?

Answer (score 2):

You can reverse the column, take the incremental mean, and then reverse it back again.

```
my_df.loc[::-1, 'col_1'].expanding().mean()[::-1]

# 0    30.0
# 1    35.0
# 2    40.0
# 3    45.0
# 4    50.0
# Name: col_1, dtype: float64
```

A similar ndarray-level approach could be to use `np.cumsum` and divide by the increasing number of elements.

```
np.true_divide(np.cumsum(my_df.col_1.values[::-1]), 
               np.arange(1, len(my_df)+1))[::-1]

# array([30., 35., 40., 45., 50.])
```

Comment: That is incredibly elegant. Thank you.

Comment: @AmiTavory Yeah it is new as of [0.18.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0180-enhancements-moments), before that there were the top-level functions like `pd.expanding_mean`.